# HTML5 on OpenBSD?

Tags: openbsd, browser, web

What do I need to install/configure to make an HTML5 such as Youtube's alternate player page work? Install a browser that's supporting it by default, or I have to do other things to?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Rendering HTML is a function of the browser, not the operating system. Don't let Microsoft's patently [ridiculous marketing of "native support"](http://arewenativeyet.com/) delude you into thinking otherwise.

1. Install a modern browser.
2. Live happily ever after.